# How this javascript function works?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/Rangaraj/9ugd5tL1/

`function addTaskElement(taskName) {   }`

In the above link (jsfiddle link), there is a function called **addTaskElement()**. In that, when the selectors (eg:button.delete) clicked, **tasks related to the particular selector only gets affected**. **But the selectors are classes**. How is this working. Is it related to closure kind of thing? Or a simple javascript?

Answer (score 1):

It's using a contextual selector to restrict the elements selected, note the `$task` as the second parameter:

```
$("button.delete", $task).click(function () {
    $task.remove();
});
```

This is selecting on the `button.delete` elements within the `$task` jQuery object. It is the equivalent of:

```
$task.find('button.delete').click(fn);
```

Further information in the [API](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-selector-context)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. i understand about contextual selector. but the $task is the clone of that task template. so every time the task added, the list is same template (ie. the elements with same classes) so when clickeing on a delete button, how come it removes the parent li(task). there is no use of this object.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. The contextual selector is the reason it works, if you understand that then there is your answer.

Comment: we can create n no of tasks. every element like button.move-down, button.move-up, button.delete are the child of the same variable $task in other words .task div. how these elements know their parent. there is no parent selector on click.

Comment: That's right, the parent is in the selector - it's the `$task` variable.

Comment: sorry to ask you again. say for example, we have created 4 tasks. every element in  each task is the child of $task variable. so when we click the delete button in the 2nd task how does the button knows it has to remove the 2nd task. because all buttons have the same parent .task.                   $("button.delete", $task).click(function () {
        $task.remove();
    });

Comment: Because the `$task` within that handler is the one which it was instantiated with.

Comment: sorry to ask you again. say for example, we have created 4 tasks. every element in  each task is the child of $task variable. so when we click the delete button in the 2nd task how does the button knows it has to remove the 2nd task. because all buttons have the same parent .task.                   $("button.delete", $task).click(function () {
        $task.remove();
    }); when we create the 4th task, the $task will be the 4th list. so when we click on delete in 2nd task, how the button removes the 2nd task exactly?

Comment: I just answered that. Every question you've asked has been the exact same, and I've answered them. If you're still confused I would suggest you do some background research yourself using Google.